# If $x \in (0,1)$ then how do you show the inequality $r > s > 0$ implies $x^r < x^s$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

This post is related to the question [What is an easy way to prove the equality $r > s > 0$ implies $x^r > x^s$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/69703/7980) which is essentially the same question reduced to the unit interval.  In particular I was wondering if there was a simple proof for the following inequality:

Let $x \in (0,1)$ and $r,s \in \mathbb{R}$

> How do you show the inequality $r > s > 0$ implies $x^r < x^s$?

Comment: Hint: $x^r = x^s x^{r-s}$.

Comment: Hint: apply the answer to [the other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/69703/7980) to $1/x$.

Comment: Could you edit your title to ask the same thing as the question? [0, 1] isn't the same as (0, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r-s>0$ and $\log x<0$ since $0< x<1$

Therefore $(r-s)\log x<0\implies \log x^{r-s}<0\implies x^{r-s}<1\implies x^r<x^s$

For  $x=0,1$ it doesn't happens

Alternative Solution:

Let $f(x)=a^x$ where $0<a<1$ then $f'(x)=(\ln a)a^x<0 $ for all $x$ since $0<a<1 $.

Therefore $f(p)>f(q)$ if $p<q\implies a^p>a^s$ if $p<s$

Answer (score 1):

You need to take $x\in(0,1)$, not in $[0,1]$: it isn’t true if $x=0$ or $x=1$. Use [Gerry Myerson’s argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69703/what-is-an-easy-way-to-prove-the-equality-r-s-0-implies-xr-xs/69708#69708) from the previous question: the only change is that if $0<x<1$, $\log x$ is negative, so $r>s$ implies that $r\log x < s\log x$.